# LC_MONETARY it_IT@utf8 shows euro symbol before amount with PHP

Tags: php, locale

Setting the locale information as:

```
$locale = 'it_IT';
$moneyFormat = '%n';

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, $locale.'.utf8');
$optionPrice = money_format($moneyFormat, floatval($option->optionPrice));
```

The price is shown as:

```
€ 23
```

instead

```
23 €
```

I've found the locale identifier p_sign_posn to set the position of the currency symbol but I don't know how to modify it and apparently it's set by default to 1 for the IT locale.

Anybody could enlightenment me to find a clever solution?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: The locale for Italy is apparently installed on the system**

```
vmamp@AMP30:~> locale -a | grep it
it_CH
it_CH.utf8
it_IT
it_IT.utf8
it_IT@euro
```

Answer (score 1):

To use locale-aware function you have to have the requested locale installed on your computer. If the requested locale is not presented, the call to `setlocale` **fails** and nothing is changed.

For instance, I have `es_ES` locale installed, but no `it_IT`:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_ES.utf8');
echo money_format($moneyFormat, floatval(12))
// ⇒ 12,00 €
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.utf8');
echo money_format($moneyFormat, floatval(12))
// ⇒ $12.00
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT.utf8');
echo money_format($moneyFormat, floatval(12))
//   FAIL!!!
// ⇒ $12.00
```

As you can see, the latter call was ignored (`setlocale` returned `0`.) So the problem you encountered is not with a position of eurosign; it’s likely a lack of `it_IT` l10n installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have thought in this situation but the locale for Italy is properly. I've edited my question with this information.

Comment: `it_IT@euro` in the list of locales puts the idea into my mind that it’s _the one_ to show euro sign properly.

Comment: We have tried this locale as well and the currency is still shown as €23. It seems that it is the correct way [http://www.evertype.com/standards/euro/formats.html], but I've found different Italian pages with the format requested from out client 23€

Comment: Aye, I see. Then you probably will need to hack italian :(

Comment: Yes, it is what we are going to do. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

For italian currency mode you can do:

$money = substr(money_format('%.2n',$number), 4).' €';

given $number = 77500

you get

77.500,00 €